# ") was unexpected at this time." running nested IF in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Not sure why this is happening. Tried looking up... looks fine I think.

```
IF not (%5) == () (
    call %antPath% -f %buildFile% runSoapUI -DserviceName=%1 -DoperationName=%2 -DinputData=%3 -DlogID=%4 -DtestType=%5
) ELSE (
    IF not (%4) == () (
        call %antPath% -f %buildFile% runSoapUI -DserviceName=%1 -DoperationName=%2 -DinputData=%3 -DlogID=%4 -DtestType=FILE
    ) ELSE (
        call %antPath% -f %buildFile% help
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `if not (a) == ()` to `if not [a] == []` (both of them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Mat said, it's a bad idea to use brackets in the if statements.
Better is the use of quotes, as they prevent problems with many special characters like spaces, `<>&|()` in the content of %n

You could also get problems with your call statements if there is in any variable a `)`.

You could solve this with delayed expansion.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
IF not "%5" == "" (
    call !antPath! -f !buildFile! runSoapUI -DserviceName=%1 -DoperationName=%2 -DinputData=%3 -DlogID=%4 -DtestType=%5
) ELSE (
    IF not "%4" == "" (
        call !antPath! -f !buildFile! runSoapUI -DserviceName=%1 -DoperationName=%2 -DinputData=%3 -DlogID=%4 -DtestType=FILE
    ) ELSE (
        call !antPath! -f !buildFile! help
    )
)
```